# How group list elements by parent ID like tree in c# MVC4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, tree, comments

I have Comment model like this:

```
public class Comment
    {
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int UserWhoTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to show comments **one under another by parentID** . Parent Comments will seems in `div`, child Comments will seems in

```
<ul>
   <li>
      child comments go here
   </li>
</ul>
```

For example,

```
  <ul>
       <li>
          <div>
               parent comments go here
          </div>
          <ul>
             <li>
                 child comments go here
             </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

I firstly need to collect Comments with LINQ **like tree** and then apply it like shown above in view. Any links or advice please.

**Edit:**

I created model as

```
public class CommentListModel
{
    public Comment Comment{ get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

And I collected all comments in 1 list:

```
List<CommentListModel>  CommentHierarchy = MyService.GetCommentHierarchy();
```

**Now, I need to show  CommentHierarchy  in view like tree hierarchy. Please help.**

Comment: what view engine are you using?

Comment: I am using razor, c#, mvc 4

Comment: do you have a collection of comments?

Comment: yes, my DBcontext has CommentSet table:
public DbSet<Comment> CommentSet { get; set; }


For example, I get comments of any project like this:

var commentsByProjectId = Database.CommentSet.Where(e => e.ProjectId == projectId).ToList();

Comment: since you have a collection, you can do a @foreach() {} loop in razor and get done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the "Childs" Property of CommentListModel to be a collection of CommentListModel like so:

```
public class CommentListModel
{
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public List<CommentListModel> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Create a partial view as a display template (put file under DisplayTemplates folder) for CommentListModel:

```
@model CommentListModel
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Comment.Text)</div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Childs)
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your parent view, simply call:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m)
```

Assuming the model of the parent view is a collection of CommentListModel objects.

This will allow your list to recurse as deeply as your collection goes.